# HTML/CSS Frontend Framework that does not use javascript?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I'm looking for a html/css frontend framework (sth like boostrap) but that does not use javascript. I develop a "hidden tor" project an most tor users does not have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know only about [Purecss](http://purecss.io/). It doesn't have very massive functionality, but it's nice and small, probably it will serve well for some not very complicated purposes

Answer (score 1):

You may try these:

[Pure from yahoo](http://purecss.io/)

[Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua/)

[Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)